# How to set WebDrivers(chrome, Firefox,etc.) path in build.gradle rather than setting it in code

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, build.gradle

I would like to set the WebDrivers path in build.gradle rather than setting the absolute path of the driver. This would help me from not checking-in the .exe into the repo.

I am setting the driver as
`System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");` in code.
Instead of the specifying the "/path/to/chromedriver" in code, I would like it to be picked/set by gradle whenever the test runs.

Tried below in build.gradle

```
test {systemProperty "webdriver.chrome.driver",
         classpath.find {
             it.name.contains("selenium-chrome-driver")
         }
     println "Getting system properties"
     println System.getProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver")
    }
```

But each I run the test, I get **null**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use WebDriverManager( https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager ) to manage your drivers.

https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager#basic-usage shows the simple way to add via gradle

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation("io.github.bonigarcia:webdrivermanager:4.3.1")
}
```

and code usage:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setupClass() {
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
}

@Before
public void setupTest() {
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I would not like to use the bonigarcia or any other library. How can I achieve this without any external library.

Comment: Any reason why not? Otherwise you'll end up recreating what they do for you: downloading a binary from the internet and accessing it.